# so long v as long

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

Is there any difference between so long and as long:

1. You are allowed to do other work in your own time ***so long*** as you declare it.
2. The car will keep running ***as long*** as you take good care of it.

Are they interchangeable?

Comment: Yes, they're equivalent and interchangeable in both your examples.

Comment: They are equivalent, but "so long as" is more akin to "if," whereas "as long as" is more akin to "while." "X will happen so long as Y condition is true." This means that if Y is true, X will be true. "As long as" however, carries more of a feeling of time with it. "X will be true as long as Y remains true." This implies more of a limited duration. In the given example, declaring your work means you're allowed to do it, and that's all. But if you stop taking care of your car, then it may stop running. Example 1. would make less sense with "as long as," but example 2 could make sense either way.

Answer (score 0):

In this construction, the two phrases are identical in meaning, and can be used intercahngably. They both mean "provided that".

However, thjere are other usages of these phrases which are not idetical. "as long as" can be sued for comparing times.

> Judy worked as long as John so she should be paid as much

"so long as" could not be used in that construction.

"So long as" can be sued to mean "while". For example

> So long as people vomit crimes, we will need laws.

In this usage "as long as" would be possible, but less common.